# Discord.js databases to use

Tags: discord.js

I'm coding my first discord bot and I need some help in knowing which database would fit for this job so far I have tried saving my needed data in a json file but encountered some issues and heard some say that it's a bad practice my bot is a virtual food delivery bot which I used to store data like this in the json file

```
{
    "001": {
        "guildID": "some data here",
        "customer": "some data here",
        "order details": "some data here"
    }
}
```

usually these data get deleted after an "order" is delivered so I don't think I would need a big database?
any suggestions for better ways to store these data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, JSON is a poor choice for a database. According to the Discord.JS maintainers:

> "JSON files are prone to corruption when written to and read from a lot, which is why they should not be used as a form of database"

The Discord.JS guide includes 2 tutorials on setting up databases using [Keyv](https://discordjs.guide/keyv/) or [Sequalize](https://discordjs.guide/sequelize/).