# Is there a way to keep track of a timeout even after the bot was restarted?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Basically is a tempban command I'm working on but the issue is the normal way I would do it, I mean by using timeout, doesn't work because I want it to keep track over a long period of time like around 300 days.
Is there maybe a package I could use or some API of which time I could check? If yes how would I check it every day?

Comment: I believe [Cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cron) would be a good tool for this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain persistant data between bot restarts, you need to use a database like mysql, sqlite, or mongodb, or you could just save temp-ban information into a file that your bot then reads back as required.

Comment: Id like not to complicate my code with databases so Il try using a json and then call it on ready, but the issue is Idk any ways to store the curent passed time since the ban wen the bot stops

Comment: JSON is a poor choice for a database. Refer to [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67392581/discord-js-databases-to-use/67392829#67392829) for more information.

Comment: Im willing to use other ways of storage but how do I update the elapsed time wen the bot is sutting is there any way to make the bot  repeat an action like in 24h and so on?

Comment: Use DateTime. Instead of saying "unban in 3 hours" say "unban at current time + 3 hours". This way you can store an "unban time" and if `current_time > unban_time` then you can unban the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the banned userID and unban time in mongodb or any other database of your choice, and then create a functions that will run when the bot starts, which will keep checking the database periodically to see if it can find any user whose banned duration is over and then unban that user.

The function can be either created using a simple setInterval or u can use something like [node-cron](https://www.npmjs.com/package//node-cron).

You can also use redis to do this using it's inbuilt key expiration events. There is nice a [youtude video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ELquTSRANSs&ab_channel=WornOffKeys) that will show you how to achieve that.